# "moving forward" and "starting now" instead of "from now on"

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning

> A: I think we need to trust, ***moving forward***, that decisions
>   affecting the entire unit will not be made without  discussion. (A
>   tells this to B because B did something by himself that affected the
>   entire unit. So A is warning him right now.

What does marked phrase mean here? How does marked phrase modify the sentence? Is it a reduced clause or participle?

Can I just use "moving forward" or "starting now" instead of "from now on" ?

> a- You will report to me ***from now on***.
>
> b- You will report to me, ***starting now***. (Is it okay to leave that phrase, starting now,  like this?)
>
> c- You will report to me, ***moving forward***. (Is it okay to leave that phrase, starting now,  like this?)

Comment: moving forward is business jargon for from now on, which started in the 1990's.

Answer (score 2):

In this context, it means "in the future". It's somewhat redundant, since "will" already signifies the future, but it emphasizes that one is specifically discusses the future, and implies a contrast with past developments.

Comment: "Moving forward" is one of those very annoying phrases that people use in business nowadays.

Comment: @Accumulation Thanks. What is "moving forward" reduced from here?

Comment: @ Michael Harvey in general I agree that today's business talk is full of Buzz words and titles that have been created for no reason as there meanings are adequately covered by words used for several generations or, in some cases even centuries. However Moving forward is one of the less annoying ones its just a alternative way of saying to progress or to modernise

Answer (score 1):

**moving forward,**
In this context, it **means more** than just **in the future**.

"**from now on**" & "**starting now**". Can not be used as replacements because they convey only half of the meaning. Where as both **"from now on**" & "**starting now"** have a date line reference of now, at this moment and moving forward. **A new beginning**.

Moving Forward means a) setting what ever has happened to one side,b) then moves on to refers to a new strategy for the future. Thus **Moving forward** **joins the past and the future**. It has a more inclusive meaning. **The situation evolves or progresses rather than starts anew**

> **move-forward** [Your Dictionary](https://www.yourdictionary.com/move-forward)
>   Verb (third-person singular simple present moves forward, present participle moving forward, simple past and past participle moved forward)
>
> **To progress, modernise**

Answer (score 0):

> A: I think we need to trust, moving forward, that …

To me, **starting now** or **from now on** mean an intentional sharp change from past practice, but **moving forward** does not; it says this is what we need in the future, *whether or not* it has been true in the past.  ‘A’ may be hinting that ‘B’ violated a trust that *ought to have existed* all along.